# Calling an array in pokedex project

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, variables, getelementbyid

I have recently designed a pokedex and have created an array with all the pokemon ID's and class's like so.

```js
const pokedex = [
{
  pokemon: 'bulbasaur',
  dexInfo: [
    { dexName: 'bulbasaur-name' },
    { specs: 'bulbasaur-specs' },
    { desc: 'bulbasaur-desc' }
  ],
  dexNumber: 'bulbasaur-no',
  primaryType: 'grass-one',
  secondaryType: 'poison-two'
}
];

function turnOnPokedex() {
  console.log('turn-on')
  pokemonImage.classList.remove('hide')
  pokemonInfo.classList.remove('hide')
  pokemonTypeOne.classList.remove('hide')
  pokemonTypeTwo.classList.remove('hide')
  dexNo.classList.remove('hide')

  for (let i = 0; i < pokedex.length; i++) {
  
  }

  nextPokemon()
}

let pokemonImage = document.getElementById('pokemon')
let pokemonInfo = document.getElementById('dex-info')
let pokemonTypeOne = document.getElementById('type-one')
let pokemonTypeTwo = document.getElementById('type-two')
let dexNo = document.getElementById('dex-number')
```

```html
<img id="bulbasaur" src="images/pokemon/bulbasaur.png" width="250" height="220">
<div id="bulbasaur-no"><strong>001</strong></div>
<div id="bulbasaur-name">Bulbasaur</div>
<div id="bulbasaur-specs">
  Species: Seed Pokemon<br><br>
  Height: 2'04<br><br>
  Weight: 15.2lbs(6.9kg)
</div>
<div id="bulbasaur-desc">
A strange seed was planted on<br><br> its back at birth. The plant<br><br> sprouts and grows with this<br><br> Pokémon.
<div\>
<div class="grass-one">Grass</div>
<div class="poison-two">Poison</div>
```

However whenever I try to call this function, the entire pokedex shows up at once instead of just starting with bulbasaur. Any ideas on how to resolve this issue? Thank you.

Comment: Your for loop in the Javascript is empty - did you mean to call `nextPokemon()` inside?

Comment: Can you update these code snippets to a runnable [mcve] which demonstrates the problem?  We don't know what calls `turnOnPokedex()`, what `nextPokemon()` does, what elements any of those variables specifically reference, why there's an empty loop that does nothing, etc., etc.

Comment: What does `nextPokemon()` do?

Comment: I did have 'pokedex[i]' in there originally but I removed it as it was not working

Comment: Why do you put `()` around all the strings in the obect?

Comment: What are the variables `pokemonImage`, `pokemonInfo`, etc.?

Comment: Typo here: `<div\>` should be `</div>`

Comment: so far the nextPokemon() function is as follows: function nextPokemon(pokemon, dexInfo, dexNumber,
    primaryType, secondaryType) {
    pokedex = pokemon.forEach([currentPokedexIndex])
}

Comment: Put code in the question, not a comment.

Comment: In addition to [editing the question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77128518/edit) to include your code, please also encapsulate all of that code into a [runnable code snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) which demonstrates the problem, rather than disparate segments which may or may not work together in your actual code.

Comment: I thought you need to put ( ) for if you are trying to call an ID or class from the HTML file.

Comment: sorry, I'm new to using stackoverflow.

Comment: @ryanl: I've converted your code to a runnable code snippet.  As you can see, it does not demonstrate the problem you are trying to describe.  Please take some time to update that code snippet to demonstrate the problem and describe specifically what problem you are observing.

Comment: Think about using a generic ID for the HTML elements. For example `id="pokemon"` instead of `bulbasaur`. Then inject the text inside of the div with id `pokemon` in the `nextPokemon()` method. There's not enough information to answer the question. Please add more information.

Answer (score 1):

Your JSON data should not look like your HTML markup. Each Pokédex entry should be fairly flat in nature. Since Pokémon typically have one or two types, storing them in an array is a better choice.

If you want a prev/next button in the Pokédex, you will have to store the current index. Also, you should avoid using ID attributes. Class names are a much more versatile approach.

```js
const entry = document.querySelector('.pkmn-entry');
let currentIndex = 0;

const pokedex = [{
  id: 1,
  name: 'Bulbasaur',
  species: 'Seed Pokemon',
  height: 0.7, /* meters */
  weight: 6.9, /* kg */
  description: 'A strange seed was planted on its back at birth. The plant sprouts and grows with this Pokémon',
  types: ['grass', 'poison'],
}, {
  id: 2,
  name: 'Ivysaur',
  species: 'Seed Pokemon',
  height: 1.0, /* meters */
  weight: 13.0, /* kg */
  description: 'When the bulb on its back grows large, it appears to lose the ability to stand on its hind legs.',
  types: ['grass', 'poison'],
}, {
  id: 3,
  name: 'Venusaur',
  species: 'Seed Pokemon',
  height: 2.0, /* meters */
  weight: 100.0, /* kg */
  description: 'The plant blooms when it is absorbing solar energy. It stays on the move to seek sunlight.',
  types: ['grass', 'poison'],
}];

render();

function turnOnPokedex() {
  entry.classList.toggle('hide');
}

function navigate(button) {
  const offset = button.dataset.direction === 'prev' ? -1 : 1;
  // Cycle through
  currentIndex = (currentIndex + offset + pokedex.length) % pokedex.length;
  render();
}

function render() {
  const p = pokedex[currentIndex];
  
  const resource = `${p.id.toString().padStart(4, '0')}${p.name}.png`;
  entry.querySelector('.pkmn-img').src = getAbsolutePath(resource, 'https://archives.bulbagarden.net/media/upload');
  entry.querySelector('.pkmn-img').alt = p.name;
  entry.querySelector('.pkmn-no').textContent = p.id.toString().padStart(3, '0');
  entry.querySelector('.pkmn-name').textContent = p.name;
  entry.querySelector('.pkmn-specs').innerHTML = `
    Species: ${p.species}<br />
    Height: ${metersToFeet(p.height)}<br />
    Weight: ${round(kgToLbs(p.weight), 1)} lbs
  `;
  entry.querySelector('.pkmn-desc').textContent = p.description;
  entry.querySelector('.pkmn-types').innerHTML =
    p.types
      .map(type => `<div data-type="${type}">${capitalize(type)}</div> `)
      .join('');
}

function getAbsolutePath(filename, baseUrl) {
  const hash = CryptoJS.MD5(filename.replace(/ /g, '_')).toString();
  return `${baseUrl}/${hash[0]}/${hash.substring(0, 2)}/${filename}`;
};

function capitalize(word) {
  return word[0].toUpperCase() + word.slice(1).toLowerCase();
}

function metersToFeetAndInches(meters) {
  const inches = meters * 39.3701;
  return {
    feet: Math.floor(inches / 12),
    inches: Math.round(inches % 12)
  };
}

function metersToFeet(meters) {
  const { feet, inches } = metersToFeetAndInches(meters);
  return `${feet}'${inches}"`;
}

function kgToLbs(kg) {
  return kg * 2.20462;
}

function round(n, p = 2) {
  return (e => Math.round(n * e) / e)(Math.pow(10, p));
}
```

```css
.pkmn-entry .pkmn-no {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.pkmn-entry .pkmn-types div {
  display: inline-block;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}

.pkmn-types [data-type] { padding 0.5rem; }
.pkmn-types [data-type="grass"] { background: #AFA; }
.pkmn-types [data-type="poison"] { background: #FDF; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/4.1.1/core.min.js" integrity="sha512-t8vdA86yKUE154D1VlNn78JbDkjv3HxdK/0MJDMBUXUjshuzRgET0ERp/0MAgYS+8YD9YmFwnz6+FWLz1gRZaw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/4.1.1/md5.min.js" integrity="sha512-3sGbaDyhjGb+yxqvJKi/gl5zL4J7P5Yh4GXzq+E9puzlmVkIctjf4yP6LfijOUvtoBI3p9pLKia9crHsgYDTUQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<button type="button" onclick="turnOnPokedex()">Toggle Pokedex</button>
<div class="pkmn-entry hide">
  <img class="pkmn-img" src="" alt="Bulbasaur" width="250" height="220">
  <div class="pkmn-no">001</div>
  <div class="pkmn-name">Bulbasaur</div>
  <div class="pkmn-specs">
    Species: Seed Pokemon<br />
    Height: 2'04<br />
    Weight: 15.2lbs(6.9kg)
  </div>
  <div class="pkmn-desc">
    A strange seed was planted on its back at birth. The plant sprouts and grows with this Pokémon.
  </div>
  <div class="pkmn-types">
    <div data-type="grass">Grass</div>
    <div data-type="poison">Poison</div>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <button type="button" data-direction="prev" onclick="navigate(this)">Prev</button>
    <button type="button" data-direction="next" onclick="navigate(this)">Next</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for this @Mr. Polywhirl and everyone else for the advice. I will use this and follow up on it.